# Passing values to form when initializing in views django?

Tags: python, django

forms.py

```
class PermissionForm(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.rolesChoices = kwargs.pop('rolesChoices')
        super(PermissionForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        print(self.rolesChoices)
        self.fields['roles'].queryset = self.rolesChoices
        print(self.fields['roles'].queryset)
    roles = forms.ModelChoiceField(
        queryset=None, widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple, empty_label=None)
```

views.py

```
def privileges(request):
    rolesChoices = Permission.objects.filter(
        content_type=ContentType.objects.get_for_model(Group))
    for role in rolesChoices:
        role.name = role.name.replace("group", "role")
    form = PermissionForm(rolesChoices=rolesChoices)
    return render(request, 'crm/privileges.html', {'form': form})
```

I am passing group objects to my form when I am initializing it in views.But I am done a small change, I replaced group with role.So the problem is role get changed with group automatically.I don't know why it's happenging.

For example `self.roleChoices` contains `Can add role`
When I assign `self.roleChoices` to `self.fields['roles'].queryset` it changes to `Can add group`

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that, when you do the following:

```
    for role in rolesChoices:
        role.name = role.name.replace("group", "role")
```

You execute the queryset, which creates a list of results cached in the queryset.

Then, when you do:

```py
self.fields['roles'].queryset = self.rolesChoices
```

You actually call `self.fields['roles']._set_queryset(self.rolesChoices)` as [`queryset` is a property](https://github.com/django/django/blob/3.1/django/forms/models.py#L1223-L1230) that ensures calling `.all()` on your queryset.

If you need to operate such changes on the results before showing it in your form, I would recommend to use a `ChoiceField` instead of a `ModelChoiceField`. Thus you can set the `choices` attribute as you wish.

However, in this case you might be able to bypass the property using `_queryset`: `self.fields['roles']._queryset = self.rolesChoices`. Although you might face other issues later if the queryset is called again with `.all()` or `.filter()`.